# Domain-Event-Driven Architecture

Tags: java, architecture, soa

I'm starting a Web Application project in Java and I've been doing some research on which architecture to take.

It's going to have *n* services (Billing, Reporting, Sales, CRM, etc) which depending on the service, may or may not work as standalone webapp.

I really like the Domain-Event-Driven approach. Thing is, I've never done such a big project before and I would appreciate a lot hearing some thoughts and tips on which way to go.

With the Domain-Event-Driven Architecture, my main doubts are:

- If I need some data from other service, is it right to create a Web Service for it and access all data from there? I would be generating deeper coupling here and that's kind of what I want to avoid. Which other approches are there?
- How is persistence done? Has each service it's own DB? No relations between services' DBs?
- What if a service fails? It will loose all messages and therefore won't be able to take the corresponding actions, right? Any workarounds?
- What if ActiveMQ fails?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I need some data from other service, is it right to create a Web Service for it and access all data from there?

Yes.

> I would be generating deeper coupling here and that's kind of what I want to avoid.

False.  You should explain what coupling you think is going to happen here.

> Which other approches are there?

Service Oriented Architectures do this all the time.  The alternatives are **more** tightly coupled.

> How is persistence done? Has each service it's own DB?

Yes.   Services stand alone.  Often services are part of large packaged applications.

> No relations between services' DBs?

Correct.

> What if a service fails?

Bummer.  Requests back up in the queues until you restart the service.

> It will loose all messages and therefore won't be able to take the corresponding actions, right? Any workarounds?

False.  Totally false.  You can use persistent, reliable message queues.

> What if ActiveMQ fails?

Then the world as we know it ends.  What do you mean by "fail"?  It's a fairly loosely-coupled system that allows lots of problems to happen and get resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time! That was helpful.

Comment: @alan.reid: A message is is not a "thing".  It doesn't crash.  A host that's got part of the queue might stop, but the queue, as a whole, doesn't exist in any one place.

Comment: No, I know, excuse the confusion, I meant the message broker itself. That doesn't really matter that much right now, it was just a hypothetical scenario. Thanks again!